# UnicodeEncodeError: with arabic data

Tags: python, excel, file

my code:

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import  xlsxwriter
import codecs 
import sys
import pprint


df=pd.read_excel('ar.xlsx',"Sheet1")
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df) 
for column in new_df:
    new_df2=(new_df[column].str.split("/ ") )
    new_df2=new_df.apply(pd.Series)
    new_df3=(new_df2.to_string())
    new_df4=new_df3.split()


print '\n'.join([ str(myelement) for myelement in new_df4 ])
```

i have an excel file with arabic words and i want split sentences to multiple rows
it works with english [english](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pix3h.jpg)
but it is not working with arabic i will get this erorr

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: which `operating system` you are using ? and which `IDE`

Comment: iam using windows 10 and python 2.7 by anaconda

Comment: `import sys` then `print(sys.stdin.encoding)` and give me the output.

Comment: sir it still gives me the same erorr when i try arabic file

Comment: I'm asking you to run this simple code away from your code !

Comment: but when i try english file at the end it prints none because i wrote print(sys.stdin.encoding)  at the end

Comment: it prints none in a simple way

Comment: `df=pd.read_excel('ar.xlsx',"Sheet1", encoding='utf-8')` << use this

Comment: i were trying to detect which encoding your system use.. such as https://onlinegdb.com/H1zyogV2H

Comment: it's still the same error what should i do?

Comment: i guess it should be UTF-8                                                                                                   https://www.onlinegdb.com/H1zyogV2H